# European A&M Gathering: Feeler Survey & Location Proposals

Tags: discussion, community-events

It's been talked about in chat for a while, so let's do something about it!

I am volunteering to organise a European get-together for A&M if there is sufficient interest.

---

For the first phase of this adventure, we must first decide **what we want to do and where we want to go.** Thus I ask you readers to fill out this survey:

**[A&M European Meetup survey](http://goo.gl/forms/33hSJwwYnp)**

***Note**: Non-europeans may attend too if they wish. Beware flight costs though!*

After a few weeks I will post a summary of the results of the survey here and expand on our options a bit more once we know what's reasonably achievable.

[image]

Feel free to bring your 2D significant others.

*This meetup is not affiliated with Stack Exchange as a company, etc, etc.*

Comment: If you require any assistance in organizing or information, feel free to contact me ;)

Comment: Please use the [otaku tourism](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19588/otaku-tourism) chat room as a hub for discussion.

Comment: Same goes for me, if I can be of help feel free to contact me :)!

Comment: Ah, Melonpan...

Comment: Don't forget to include graphs in the results summary.

Comment: Also, if we do get a fairly large number of people interested and nobody is against it, we could make a short promotional video on our community and how we're the best one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good Morning European A&M'rs.

It's been a week since the survey was put up and there have been a total 7 responses.

Where people hail from (Alphabetically):

- France 1
- Germany 1
- Ireland 1
- Netherlands 3
- UK 2

[image: ![enter image description here]

All Western Europe, so air/boat/train fares won't be too bad, hooray! This seems to satisfy most people's travelling arrangements too:

- Anywhere in Europe 4
- Surrounding/Nearby Countries 2
- Dependent on personal circumstances at the time of the trip 1
- English-Speaking Countries only

[image: ![enter image description here]

It makes sense for at least one person not to travel, so what do our mother countries have to offer?

---

**France**:

French food! Japan expo! - the largest Japanese convention in Europe - Summer. (mentioned by 2 users)

**Ireland**:

Eirtakon is the largest convention in Ireland, with >3000 attendees. There are some smaller cons too, but it's the main one of the year. There's not many otaku things in Ireland, but there are lots of pubs and tours if people want something different.

It'll probably rain.

**UK**

A lovely convention (Name not given)

Terrible beaches

MCM Comic con which isn't just anime, so there should be something for everyone (although I think seeing as we are an Anime site that should be ok :P) & includes a fun party at the end.

Lots of other things to do in london, that are not anime related - if people want to do other stuff.

Expensive.

**Netherlands**

TomoFair - 3rd October (Japanese Culture Event) [Unfortunately, I think this is probably too soon for people to be organised around]

AnimeCon - June 10th-12th in the Hague

Several conventions

beaches

lovely bars

sightseeing spots.

cosplay meet-ups in parks - we could easily gather at one of those.

4 people from here - of which 3 will probably go (3 answered the survey)

**Germany**

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Other Events Suggested**

*"Kidnapping Toshinou Kyouko and putting them in a Tomato Onesie"* >:(

---

In terms of organization & events, it seems maybe having a **flexible** itinerary would be best, where we could override it if the group wanted to. Or meet and have a backup itinerary.

[image: ![enter image description here]

It looks like not many are interested in doing a trade/swap - so perhaps interested users could organise any of this beforehand.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Most people are uncertain about cosplaying - but no one selected the option where they didn't want cosplay at all:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

--

Things to consider:

- *I'm a tomato and I don't want to get squished*
- *fear of heights*
- *Avoid comiket-sized crowds* (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ermNqkUUiJw for reference)
- Joint booking of accommodation could be useful. [Note - I don't want to be responsible for this, but if you would like to do amongst yourselves, that's fine]

---

I think from this, the best options are either the UK or Netherlands.
In the coming days I will put up another survey after researching what particular events we could go to & such.

Please feel free to comment on these results and/or suggest additional info for the next stage.

Comment: I didn't have time to fill one in >_<

Comment: As for accommodation, I can most likely fetch us a decent discount due to my current employment, if it is located in the netherlands, germany or france ;)

Comment: @ChenOrihara I can add in your thoughts if you still want to fill it out

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Added my entry, granted abit late :p, though it wouldnt change the stats much I reckon

Comment: @ChenOrihara no worries :) you have been included in the stats now