# European A&M Gathering: Let's Decide the Event!

Tags: discussion, events

[Now that we know there's enough interest](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2605/1530), let's start filling in the details.

First up on the *to-decide* list is **the venue/event** that we can meet up at. This way, we get an A&M Meetup **AND** another fun event - that can be enjoyed together or individually.

There were some strong suggestions in the survey, but we don't know which one is best for everyone. Therefore, this post is for **suggesting the venue you would like the Great A&M EU Meetup to be located.**

[image: by hakaru-chan1]

Feel free to elaborate on the suggestions you gave in the survey.

Obvious events are conventions / anime gatherings - but feel free to suggest anything we might find interesting! Please keep the [Locations of our users](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2605/1530) in mind though.

You can promote your choice through pictures, videos, long passages of text, cookies, whatever!

(But please use the format below)

> **Venue Proposal:** Event/Venue Name
>
> **Country**: Country Name
>
> **Date (if applicable)**: 01/01/2016
>
> **Why Should We Pick Here?** Do your best to sell it to us!
>
> **Things to bear in mind:** Is it expensive? non-english? hard to reach? safe? etc.

Comment: I've added one event from each location (avoiding events that occur too soon to prepare for). Please suggest another event if you can think of any ones that might be fun :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Venue Proposal:** [Anime Con](http://www.animecon.nl/)

**Country:** The Netherlands (The Hague)

**Date (if applicable):** Juneish 2016

**Why Should We Pick Here?**

Most of our attendees would be here - Higher turn out rate! Also people who may know the area.

[Lots of events](http://program.animecon.nl/)

Hosts a more casual [international cosplay contest](http://www.animecon.nl/program/events/cosplay-competitions/cccc) - more centered on the 'fun' of cosplay

And lots of exciting concerts!

Workshops :)

Maybe a cosplay meetup in a park?

Convention has a focus on anime

**Things to bear in mind:**

None that I know of.

[~93% of Dutch speak english to some degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_in_the_Netherlands)

Comment: And for the other 7% feel free to message me, and ill guide you through the proccess ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Venue Proposal:** [London Anime & Gaming Con](http://www.londonanimecon.com/index.php)

**Country**: England, UK

**Date (if applicable):** 5-7 Feb 2016

**Why Should We Pick Here?**

99.9999% of people will speak English

Central - Good access

Monica Rial is one of the announced guests (she's great, saw her when she visited Ireland :3 )

A little smaller, more friendly feel, less company-ish.

Opening party wooo!

**Things to bear in mind:**

London is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

**Venue Proposal:** [Japan Expo Paris](http://www.japan-expo-paris.com/en/)

**Country:** France

**Date (if applicable):** 07-10 July 2016

**Why Should We Pick Here?**

This is the largest convention in Europe. Last year saw 250,000 attendees.

The European Cosplay Gathering Finals are held here

And lots of exciting concerts from artists from Japan!

Definitely lots of things to do

**Things to bear in mind:**

Paris can be expensive.

Most of the convention is in French.