# European A&M Gathering: What should we do there?

Tags: discussion, events

[A&M has voted](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/european-am-gathering-lets-decide-the-event) and the chosen event for our EU Meetup is...

**[Anime 2016, The World Forum, The Hague, Netherlands](http://www.animecon.nl/)** This will be held from the **10th to 12th June 2016.**

[image: Pretty Picture of The Hague] [image: Pretty Picture of The Hague]

*Pretty~*

The next meta post will contain details of ticket bookings, travel, accommodation, etc. But for now **Let's decide what to do there!**

**Please suggest event ideas** here for us to do. This can be events based in the convention, or outside.

([Here's the previous Animecon programme](http://program.animecon.nl/) for potential ideas).

There is also some scope for pre/post convention events, for those that have arrived early/flying back later.

Please suggest events in this format:

> **Event Title:** Exciting A&M event
>
> **What day(s):** Range of days / Single day / Opening Hours
>
> **Details:** Short Description (unless it's a surprise/secret - in which case, we can privately talk) including any requirements such as tickets / age.

By suggesting an event, I will assume you will be somewhat willing to help out with the organization of the event (you'll have help from me and some others), Let's all get involved and make this a fun trip to remember! :)

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not a recommendation on what to do, it might be useful to keep in mind, for the things we are going to do. As I am assuming most if not all of us will be dependant on public transport.

### Accommodations in the surrounding area

For the people that still require a place to stay, here are some suggestions. They are pretty cheap, on a not to long of a distance from the station/city center/ animecon. Take note that going with groups tends to be cheaper. The total price is based on a Thursday till Monday stay. And the tourist tax tends to be €5.50/ person.

- [NH Atlantica](http://www.nh-hotels.com/hotel/nh-atlantic-den-haag)

- 1 person 109/night  - 3 persons
- Totaling on €558 for 3 people included tax
- Special: 5% discount can be obtained through me.
- 30 minutes away from Anime con / 20 minutes away from city center

- [B&B Kussengevecht](http://www.kussengevecht.nl/)

- 1 person €75/night 2 persons €80/night
- Totaling at €320 (ex tax?)

If you need any help in regards of accommodations, transport, routes feel free to give me a message, as ill most likely be able to help.

I will also offer all our A&M members that come visit a free drink on the 10th of June. Why? Well, it happens to be my birthday on June the 10th. So I think it is fairly fitting ;)

Comment: I was thinking of getting a hotel/B&B room next year anyway, so if anyone'd want to split either the B&B or hotel room costs and join em, we'd both be cheaper off :P (When in Holland, right?) And you'd have your own personal Dutch 'guide'

Answer (score 3):

**Event Title:** Visit the beach

**What day(s):** Any day with decent weather.

**Where:** Schevingen (~ 20 minutes from Animecon)

**Details:** Lots of things to do/ see around the beach in Scheveningen. Especially for Tourists.

Answer (score 3):

**Event Title:** Find the A&M **ULTIMATE SHRINE MAIDEN**

[image]

**What day(s):** Probably either day of the convention, but TBC

**Where:** at the convention

**Details:** It's likely this event will be on again this year, although perhaps under a different theme. Here's the extract from the [con website:](http://www.animecon.nl/program/events/other-events/challenge-course)

> This event will be a series of mini games where several of your abilities will be put to the test. All games will train you to become a true Shrine maiden.
>
> Are you up for the challenge? Do you have the courage, knowledge, physical strength and foolishness to pull through? Come, then we will watch as you struggle towards the finish!
>
> During this event you can join in and participate at any given time. In order to lighten the pain we will hand out pric[z?]es to all participants.
>
> What’s with the long name? Our philosophy is ‘The longer the name, the better the event’. The past few years we also had the ‘Super Golden Sparkling Idol Training’ and the ‘Super Golden Banzai Challenge Course’. I
>
> Is there anything to win? To reward participants for their great efforts we will be giving away mini prizes to those that survive!
>
> Can I participate together with friends? Participation is very flexible, you can participate solo or together with friends.

Comment: This might be interesting, it's something we can all do together as well

Answer (score 2):

**Event Title:** Go to a amusement park/ pool

**What day(s):** Any day

Answer (score 2):

**Event Title:** Cosplay Meetings

**What day(s):** Undetermined

**Where:** Undetermined

**Details:** There don't tend to be allot of cosplay meets during/ around convention times. But in case there are they would be announced about 1 month in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Event Title:** Drinking Bubble thee

**What day(s):** Any day besides sunday

**Where:** The Hague

Comment: I presume you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_tea ?

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Yep, all tough not really Japanese or anime related. There do tend to hang allot of anime fans and cosplayers (but usually regularly dressed)

Answer (score 2):

**Event Title:** Visit [*Tomato World*](http://tomatoworld.nl/nl/)

**What day(s):** TBC

**Where:** Tomatoworld ,
Zwethlaan 2 , 
2675 LB Honselersdijk, Nederland

**Details:** A tour of approximately 1.5 hours an educational advisor will learn you everything about Dutch horticulture in general and in particular about the tomato. Special interests such as technology, the growing methods or just for sustainability can be indicated in the application.

50 euro for a tour + 8per person which is a bit high for a silly event, but I could email and see if we can do a self-guided tour for less.

Comment: Does this include free tomato tasting?

Comment: Im down for this ;p

Answer (score 2):

**Event Title:** Pub Quiz

**What day(s):** (Most likely) Friday from 9 to 11.

**Where:** Convention center

**Details:**

> A pub quiz is all about having a good time while having a nice drink with friends. The setting is usually a bar or pub and there will be several rounds of questions which are worth points. The rounds  can be in theme, like a picture round, a music round and an Animecon themed round.
>
> In between rounds there will be a short break so the judges can collect your answers and count the points per team. Teams are limited to five persons per team, this is to keep things fair as more people probably know more answers.
>
> There can be as many teams as the room (and security) permits, it is also possible to join during the later rounds.

We're all members of the best Q&A site in town so I reckon we can do pretty good in this quiz! This is my personal favourite event of conventions. There's also prizes if we do well :D

**Note:** There may be an age restriction of 18 if there is alcohol being served.

Comment: If we're going as team A&M.SE, we need to get team t-shirts

Answer (score 1):

**Event Title:** Watch the Cosplay events together

**What day(s):** Saturday, Sunday Time: TBC

**Details:** We can watch a/some cosplay event(s) together and cheer others on if any of us are performing! There is also the ECG selections probably on the Saturday