# European A&M Gathering - Helpful Travel Tips & Resources (Tickets, Accommodation, etc.)

Tags: discussion

This meta post is a place for handy travel information for anyone going on our trip.

Please share anything you might find useful for the trip.

We're still gathering [ideas for what to do](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/european-am-gathering-what-should-we-do-there?cb=1) on our [other meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/european-am-gathering-what-should-we-do-there?cb=1) , so if you have any fun suggestions - or haven't voted on things you'd like to do, check that post out too.

As the type of information here differs a lot, there'll be no *format* for answers. Please just keep them brief and informative :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to cover every base, by joining us on the trip you agree to some sensible rules:

- This is not an official *Stack Exchange* event, it is an event that has been organized within the site community. As of such,
- You are ultimately responsible for your own actions. You are responsible for your personal travel/insurance/food/lodging and any other costs you may incur during the trip.
- Although our members are probably lovely, if you trust other members with belongings/shared lodging, etc. - you do so at your own risk.
- If you behave in a way that is ruining others' enjoyment of the event, you may be asked to stop participation. Unwarranted harassment of any sort won't be tolerated.
- You are free to leave/join the group at any time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an editable Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=znvnvC_9qPpg.kyr80_E8dlCk&usp=sharing) of locations which should be handy.

Feel free to add any points of interest onto the map.

Currently it has some locations of the suggested events, hotels and transport links.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Europe uses the same plug, but for those who don't, like myself and the UK - the plug type is as such:

[image]

Don't forget to bring an adapter if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The date of the convention is the **10th to the 12th of June 2016**, opening at 14:00 on Friday and closing on Sunday at 17:00.

You can buy tickets [here](https://tickets.animecon.nl/).

There is a bigger discount the earlier you book, and there are different tiers of tickets if you do not wish to attend every day:

[image]

There is a good [FAQ](http://www.animecon.nl/faq/festival-related-faq) on their site if you have any con-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

User @DmitriMX has given [some hotel suggestions here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2627/1530) - Probably best if you would like to halve the costs with another A&M'r.

The convention site has a [list of hotels](https://www.itotours.com/animecon2016/overview.aspx) too - sortable by distance to the center / cost.

There are also third party groups like [Hotels.com](http://www.hotels.com/) & [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com) as well, which are decent.