# A&M EU Meetup - The convention approaches!

Tags: discussion, events

The time approaches for 
[Anime Con](http://www.animecon.nl/), where we will have our first A&M meetup! The convention runs from **10th to 12th June.** Check out [the schedule](https://program.animecon.nl)

[image]

You can find helpful resources at a previous meta post: [European A&M Gathering - Helpful Travel Tips & Resources (Tickets, Accommodation, etc.)](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/european-am-gathering-helpful-travel-tips-resources-tickets-accommodation?lq=1) including tips for Hotels, Getting Tickets, What plugs to bring, etc.

I suggest that we meet up on the Saturday at 13:00 at the maid cafe.(if you think another time is better, comment below)

Use this meta to ask any questions, look for a cosplay partner, a roommate, etc!  :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have offered some prayers on the shrine of the SE gods and they have blessed our event with some swag!

I need some information about tshirt sizes of anyone is going so I they can provide me with the right amount.

Please fill out this survey so I can secure you some swag (**By May 31st - I need time for shipping**)

http://goo.gl/forms/653T9U81tMAFOz7C2

-Tosh

Comment: I am correct to assume this Swag will only be for those attending the meetup?

Comment: @Memor-X yep, I will be bringing them in person

Answer (score 2):

Train tickets can be expensive if you need come from afar. Me and a friend found [this page](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/s/ns-groepsretour) that allows you to buy tickets for a group which can be cheaper (keep in mind that it's only a one way ticket).

We will be ordering one for **Saturday**.

If you are interested or if you need more information you can send me a message in in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) or send me an email (awatertrevi@gmail.com).